# VBA code should capitalize first letter in sentence, but doesn't

Tags: excel, vba

I'm unsure why the following line of code is failing to capitalize the first letter of every first sentence in a cell:

```
chars.Characters(1, 1).Text = UCase(chars.Characters(1, 1).Text)
```

It does work on most of the cells, but about 1 in 6 do not.

Basic troubleshooting I attempted: 1) Made sure no spaces before the first letter, 2) Used regular UPPER formula successfully on same cell, 3) Re-typed the word, 4) Tried a different word.

Full code in case it helps:

```
 Sub ColorWords()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim chars As Range
    Dim defRng As Range
    Dim wordRng As Range
    
    Dim posB As Long
    Dim posE As Long
    Dim posQ As Long
    Dim color As Long
    
    Dim word As String
    Dim def As String
    
    Set sh = Sheets(1)
    
    Set defRng = sh.Range("D3", sh.Range("D1048576").End(xlUp).Address)
    Set wordRng = sh.Range("C3", sh.Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Address)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each cell In wordRng

        word = LCase(cell.Value)
        If IsNull(cell.Font.color) Or cell.Font.color = 0 Then GoTo NextIter
        
        color = cell.Font.color
        
        For Each chars In defRng
            chars.Characters(1, 1).Text = UCase(chars.Characters(1, 1).Text)
            def = LCase(chars.Value2)

            posB = InStr(1, def, word)
            If InStr(posB + Len(word), def, "s") = posB + Len(word) Then
            
                posE = Len(word) + 1
                
            Else
            
                posE = Len(word)
                
            End If

            Do Until posB = 0
              
               chars.Characters(posB, posE).Font.color = color
               chars.Characters(posB, posE).Font.Bold = True
               posB = InStr(posB + 1, def, word)
               If InStr(posB + Len(word), def, "s") = 1 Then
                
                    posE = Len(word) + 1
                    
               Else
                
                    posE = Len(word)
                    
               End If
               
            Loop
            
        Next chars
        
NextIter:
        
    Next cell
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub`
```

Comment: Can you post an example of a sentence that did not capitalize?

Comment: Example: 'can imperative sentence (i.e. a sentence that gives an order or command). When reading an imperative sentence, it will always sound like...'

Comment: Probably because the "If IsnNull(cell.Font.color) ..." line jumps out of the loop before the capitalization is done(?) Put a debug.assert on the line and check the colors of the cells in the wordRng. Or perhaps show a better example of your sheet so we can be more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the logic of your code inconsistent, at times to the point of confusing, and added comments to my substitute to explain. The code below will loop through all phrases in column D, capitalize their first word and remove any trailing or leading blanks.

It will then, one phrase after the other, look for existence of each word in column C. If found, the word will be given the colour it has in column C, including any trailing "s". I hope that's largely what you wanted. However, if there are small differences you may like to take the syntax I provide and move it to the location in the code where it is needed.

```
Sub ColorWords()
    ' 124

    Dim wordRng     As Range            ' words to look for
    Dim defRng      As Range            ' subject phrases
    Dim wordCell    As Range
    Dim defCell     As Range
    Dim posB        As Long             ' start of word
    Dim posE        As Long             ' length of word
    Dim Color       As Long
    Dim Word        As String
    Dim Def         As String
    
    With Worksheets(1)                  ' change to suit (suggest use of a name)
        ' syntax for specifying a cell: Cells([Row number], [Column number or name])
        ' syntax for specifying a range: Range([First wordCell], [last wordCell])
        Set wordRng = .Range(.Range("C3"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
        Set defRng = .Range(.Range("D3"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' All colours disappear upon capitalisation.
    ' Therefore call each defCell only once.
    For Each defCell In defRng
        With defCell
            Def = LCase(Trim(.Value2))          ' remove leading/trailing blanks
            Def = UCase(Left(Def, 1)) & Mid(Def, 2)
            ' your code first capitalises the first letter, then
            ' makes the entire phrase lower case, including its first letter
            .Value = Def
            .Font.Color = 0                     ' remove existing colors
        End With
        
        For Each wordCell In wordRng
            With wordCell
                Word = Trim(LCase(.Value))      ' remove leading/trailing blanks
                Color = .Font.Color             ' can't be Null
                ' Font.Color is of Long data type, which is 0 if not set
            End With
            If Color <> 0 Then                  ' 0 is the default font color (usually black)
                ' skip if Word's colour is the default
                ' vbTextCompare = case insensitive, else vbBinaryCompare
                posB = InStr(1, Def, Word, vbTextCompare)
                posE = Len(Word)
                If Mid(Def, posB + posE, 1) = "s" Then posE = posE + 1
                With defCell.Characters(Start:=posB, Length:=posE).Font
                    .Color = Color
                    .Bold = True
                End With
            End If
        Next wordCell
    Next defCell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Although the code looks at the character following the "word" I refrained from adding action to avoid colouring the word "text" in "textbook". This might easily be added if you prefer to either skip "textbook" or expand the colour to include the entire word.

Note also that I added a line of code to remove all colours from a phrase before making changes to it. This enables running of the same program on the same phrases repeatedly when words or colours in column C are modified.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are doing with the colors, but to capitalize the first letter of each sentence with in a cell, you can use Regular Expressions to determine where that letter is, and the `Characters` property to change the case to Upper.

eg:

*Note that I used early-binding so as to make use of intellisense, and it's a bit more efficient, but you can convert to late-binding if you need to*

```
'Set Reference (Tools/References) to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
Option Explicit

Sub capFirst()
    Dim R As Range, C As Range
    Dim RE As RegExp, MC As MatchCollection, M As Match
    Dim ch As String
    Const sPat As String = "^.*$"
    
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set R = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

Set RE = New RegExp
With RE
    .Pattern = sPat
    .MultiLine = True
    .Global = True
    
    For Each C In R
        If .Test(C.Value2) Then
            Set MC = .Execute(C.Value2)
                For Each M In MC
                    C.Characters(M.FirstIndex + 1, 1).Text = UCase(C.Characters(M.FirstIndex + 1, 1).Text)
                Next M
        End If
    Next C
End With
    
End Sub
```

I imagine that whatever is going on with your colors could be integrated into the above.